# Trouble to delete PostgreSQL-User

Tags: 14.04, postgresql

How can I delete the User PostgreSQL?

"It says User could not be deleted
running '/usr/sbin/userdel' failed: Child process exited with code 16"

```
postgres  2105     1  0 12:23 ?        00:00:00 /opt/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/postgres -D /opt/PostgreSQL/9.4/data
postgres  2106  2105  0 12:23 ?        00:00:00 postgres: logger process                                    
postgres  2108  2105  0 12:23 ?        00:00:00 postgres: checkpointer process                              
postgres  2109  2105  0 12:23 ?        00:00:00 postgres: writer process                                    
postgres  2110  2105  0 12:23 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process                                
postgres  2111  2105  0 12:23 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                       
postgres  2112  2105  0 12:23 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector process                           
nuc       2672  2623  0 12:25 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto postgres
```

Comment: Are you sure all processes owned by this user were stopped? Do `ps -ef|grep postgres`.

Comment: @Jos I posted the output above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete a user while there are still processes running owned by that user.

If you don't want to uninstall PostreSQL but change its running user (which is not recommended), you should stop the server process first, then `chown` all files currently owned by `postgres`. Otherwise, uninstall the server (`sudo apt-get purge postgresql`) and then try `userdel` again.

Comment: I'd like to wipe it completely from my disk. But I can't find it in the software-center.

Comment: I added that to my answer. Funnily enough you can uninstall the server while it is running (it will be stopped first).

Comment: Funnily it says it can't be found if I do: "nuc@nuc:~$ sudo apt-get purge postresql
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
E: Paket postresql kann nicht gefunden werden."

Comment: You missed a 'g' in postgresql. Ah, so did I. Apologies.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could clean up the unneeded dependencies as well.

Answer (score 1):

we can see still postgres process are running first kill all the process and then try to delete user.

Run the below commands

```
sudo kill -9 `pgrep postgres`

sudo userdel -r postgres
```

or better to uninstall postgres software.

Comment: "nuc@nuc:~$ sudo kill -9 pgrep postgres
kill: Argument konnte nicht analysiert werden: 'pgrep'
nuc@nuc:~$ sudo kill -9 pgrep postgres" - Argument couldn't be analysed.

Comment: just edited my answer this character was skipped `` by this html editor